# how do i start animation after some time in android?

Tags: android, animation, android-emulator

I want to start second animation after the end of first animation.

This is what i have done so far

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:toYDelta="50%p"
        android:duration="6000"
        android:fillEnabled="false"
        android:startOffset="7000"
        android:fillAfter="false"/>    
</set>
```

Any help will be appriciated. TIA

Comment: you can programmatically do that using playSequentially() using the animator set

Answer (score 1):

Use `AnimationListener` on your first animation, and when it is completed, start the second animation.

```
animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                 // Start the second animation.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think i told the same think :)